# Using DeepStream plugins within Gstreamer pipelines

Tags: gstreamer

I tried to use DeepStream plugins that including codec, video analytics block with TensorRT on Gstreamer pipeline. But there is a weird error.

I have tried `gst-launch-1.0` with `videotestsrc` and `ximagesink` to display on screen.

Code:

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune= zerolatency ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune= zerolatency ! h264parse ! nvdec_h264 ! nvvidconv ! ximagesink
```

Error:

```
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
nvcuvidh264dec0: Decode error result = 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it that way your resulting H.264 stream will be in 4:4:4 color sampling. Only few decoders will handle this profile.

You will have to force your encoder to use 4:2:0 instead.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! x264enc ...
```